# Setup CORS on Java Playframework 2.4.x + AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, playframework, cors

I am trying to setup CORS in java playframework 2.4.x withouth success.
My front-end app is using AngularJS 1.3.x.

I implemented the Filters class as per [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter) but my preflights OPTIONS requests from AngularJS fail without apparent reason.

This is my application.conf values regarding the filter:

NOTE: I edited the domain names (I am not the owner of example.com) ;)

```
...
play.filters.cors {
    allowedOrigins = ["http://example.com", "http://beta.example.com", "http://example.com/beta"]
    allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"]
    allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept", "Content-type"]
    preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
...
```

My play application is hosted in a separate server from the front-end:
I essentially have a sub-directory on my main hosting containing the Angular app and a subdomain pointing to the play server.

Any ideas/suggestions on where I should investigate?

Comment: I have to ask it: did you put meaningful origins in the `allowedOrigins` array and not just example.com (assuming you are not the owner of example.com) :)

Comment: @Anton Sorry I should have edited the question to specify that of course I've put my own domains. :) Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

After 3 days struggling on this I finally understood what was the problem.
Apparently a module of Cisco AnyConnect VPN was blocking all the OPTIONS preflight requests.

Nothing related to Play or AngularJS.

Here's a the link from where I found the solution:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2559-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client-may-block-cors-ajax-options-requests.htm

It was enough just to uninstall the client and boom! Everything was working again!

Posting as reference for others that might have the same problem.

Best,
E.