# Trouble-shooting CORS in Play Framework 2.4.x

Tags: java, playframework, cors, playframework-2.4

I have a java play framework 2.4.x web app providing a JSON/HTTP API. When I run my front-end HTML/JS `file:///Users/nize/tmp/index.html` calling the API on `http://localhost:9000` chrome shows

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore 
not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I have configured the web app as per the instructions given in [Play Framework 2.4.x CORS Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter):

- Update to `build.sbt`
- Added the class `Filters.java`to the root of the project (also tried `/app`)
- Added the following stanza to the `application.conf`:

  ```
  play.filters.cors {
    allowedOrigins = ["*","http://localhost"]
    #allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
    #allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
    #preflightMaxAge = 3 days
  }
  ```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
The symptoms look identical or similar to [Other very similar stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292029/setup-cors-on-java-playframework-2-4-x-angularjs). That problem was solved by reconfiguring Cisco AnyConnect VPN which was installed on the computer. I, however, don't have that software installed.

Comment: Your question helped me even before I looked at the answers below. I had implemented only the last part of the instructions in the documentation (Configuring the CORS filter in `application.conf`), missing the first two (updating `build.sbt` and adding `Filters.java`). So I battled with play until I stumbled upon your question which summarizes the steps I missed from the official documentation, and Radium's answer below which links to `reference.conf`. By the way, I was using Firefox, and also tested successfully with Chrome so this is not a Chrome-specific issue for me, and shouldn't even be.

Comment: @nize were you able to solve this? I have exact same issue. I also defined a controller method to handle OPTIONS requests but to no avail. I always get 403 using Ajax as well as Postman

Answer (score 15):

First add/edit these lines(configurations) into your conf/application.conf

```
 play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins (You can specify if you want)
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
 }
```

(Note that lines starting with '#' are commented lines.)

Then go to build.sbt and add this line.

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

Finally make a Java Class named 'Filters.java' and include this to the root directory(/app).

```
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] { corsFilter };
    }
}
```

You can refer [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter) for more information.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thanks. Note that the default app.conf file already had cors config - it is just a case of uncommenting / editing the relevant settings.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from CORSFilter to EssentialFilter

Comment: @cyril what is the play version you are using?

Comment: it is ok with corsFilter.asJava() version 2.5 thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem while following the same documentation.

Problem is with this CORS filter that you have used:

```
allowedOrigins = ["*","http://localhost"]
```

If you want to allow all origins use:

```
allowedOrigins = null
```

Follow the same for `allowedHttpMethods`

This is as per the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/resources/confs/filters-helpers/reference.conf)

To quote:

> ## The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
>
> ```
> allowedOrigins = null
> ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I think the [CORS filter in Play](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter%20CORS%20Filter) does not work! I followed step by step as but somehow I always got HTTP-403 in the browser (Chrome and Firefox) in Ajax calls. Problem is I don't even get stacktrace on server side. I think `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` in the CORS filter somehow gulp that. In the response "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header was missing so I just manually added that.

```
class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter, log: LoggingFilter) extends HttpFilters {
  def filters = {
    // CORS filter does not work
    //Seq(corsFilter, log)
    Seq(log)
  }
}
```

This is the logging filter (Credit: Play! framework)

```
class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} " +
        s"took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders(
        "Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*"   // Added this header
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar issue, I was getting 403's on requests. I solved a the problem by removing the:

```
allowedHttpHeaders=["Accept"]
```

that they use in their example configuration. I'm still not clear what the security implications of that are, however, so YMMV.

Comment: this worked for me also. I'm also not sure what the security implications of this are.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in Firefox? Chrome has some restrictions on running Ajax from local files, e.g., see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816286/jquery-ajax-post-from-local-file-to-access-a-cross-domain-not-working). If it is Chrome-specific, you can start up Chrome with a command-line switch to remove the restriction.

Comment: Good point. I tried with firefox (MacOS) also, but I got 403 (forbidden).

Comment: for me configuration working in chrome, firefox and explorer :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315501/play-framework-cors-headers/44654249#44654249

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not solve the problem for the poster, but it solved the problem for me when I had the same symptoms, and I am posting it in case it can help others in the same situation.

I had actually misunderstood how CORS is working. I have two separate Play applications, one with a REST API and one with a web interface using the REST API. I followed the instructions in the documentation page mentioned in the question, but my mistake was that I did it on the web interface application. When I instead did it on the REST API application, it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
filters = "filters.Filters"


play.filters {

  cors {

    # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
    allowedOrigins = null

    # The allowed HTTP methods. If null, all methods are allowed
    allowedHttpMethods = null

    # The allowed HTTP headers. If null, all  headers are allowed.
    allowedHttpHeaders = null
  }

}



public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    private CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] {
            corsFilter.asJava()
        };
    }

}
```