# Enabling CORS filter in Java play app

Tags: java, angularjs, cors, playframework-2.4

I tried to enable CORS filter on my java play app. I'm accessing localhost using angularjs to fetch some data. Here what I did in my play app side,

**application.conf**

```
play.http.filters = "com.de.filters.Filters"
play.filters.cors {
    allowedOrigins = null
    allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
    allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
    preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

**Filters.java**

```
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {
    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[]{corsFilter};
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to call my service, It's giving me an error,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/app/search/0/10. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

How may I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps try making allowedOrigins an empty string rather than null? `allowedOrigins = `. Or even just omit that parameter. See if it allows that. Or add localhost or 127.0.0.1 to it.

Comment: I did `allowedOrigins = ["127.0.0.1"]`. But still I can't access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines into application.conf instead.

```
play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290580/5715934) answer of me for more info.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Play 2.3 Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter), 
first add your filters to the `libraryDependencies` list in the `build.sbt` as stated below.

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

Then, in the `application.conf`, don't set `play.filters.cors.allowedOrigins` as `[null]`, it defaults to "all origins are allowed". Set a valid domain list or just ignore it. Don't forget to reference your filters:

```
play.http.filters = "filters.Filters"
```

At last, in your `Filters.filter()` method, write as below, specifying `asJava()` method, as stated in the docs.

```
public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
    return new EssentialFilter[] { 
        corsFilter.asJava()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my CORSFilter to work.  There is very little documentation on this and what is there doesn't work.  Hope this helps someone out. (Play 2.5.4)

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.mvc.EssentialAction;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;

public class MyFilters extends EssentialFilter implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    private CORSFilter corsFilter;


    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return corsFilter.asJava().apply(next);
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        EssentialFilter[] result = new EssentialFilter[1];
        result[0] = this;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Also added this into the application.conf

```
play.filters.cors{
# allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

Comment: The 2.5 Filters is apparently broken for Java but a fix is in place: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/6238/files