# Scala Play app not loading forms

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a simple setup:

routes:

```
# creates new ticket
PUT     /projects/:projectId/tickets    controllers.ProjectsController.add(projectId)
```

App Controller code looks like:

```
case class TicketData(ticketId: Option[String], ticketName: String, ticketDescription: String)

val addUpdateForm = Form(
mapping(
  "ticketId" -> optional(text),
  "ticketName" -> text,
  "ticketDescription" -> text
)(TicketData.apply)(TicketData.unapply))

def add(projectId: String) = Action { implicit request =>
  val ticket = addUpdateForm.bindFromRequest.bindFromRequest.get

  Ok(Json.toJson(cassandraClient.addTicket(projectId, ticket.ticketName, ticket.ticketDescription)))
}
```

When I try to send a req from postman (tried several combos, I have no oauth) I just always get 403 ... there is nothing really useful in logs:

```
[debug] i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.channel.ChannelMatcher
[debug] i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectMatcher
[debug] i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentMatcher
```

I'm missing something here and have no idea what to be honest.

Comment: Are you able to get a simple GET to work via your browser before trying Postman? How about a POST? Just to rule out any issues with Postman. Are your Postman settings correct? What you are doing seems correct, and I did not have to set up CORS to get simple GET/POST/PUT/DELETEs to work on my end. I have had issues with Postman though until I figured out the necessary settings.

Comment: simple GET worked (for another path) ... I'll try simple curl's and let you know how it went.

Comment: You were right, I tried simple curl's and everything works like a charm. Postman was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with the CORS configuration.

To verify it just allow every request (in `application.conf`):

```
play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

This post looks very similar:

[Trouble-shooting CORS in Play Framework 2.4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975439/trouble-shooting-cors-in-play-framework-2-4-x)

Comment: I'm already using filters, I tried this stuff but it doesn't work. I'll try to add logging filter in the evening just to see If I can provide additional details. At the moment, it's not working.

Comment: do you have `play.filters.cors.allowedOrigins = null` in your `application.conf` ?

Comment: yes, I had some stuff already there because this is my backend project, but when I remove the whole thing and set it to null it makes the same thing. I tried with exact same conf you provided.

Comment: It looks like it was a postman problem all along :) Thanks for the help