# Getting cors errors in Scala Play Framework v2.6.x

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, cors, preflight

I'm trying to get around a CORS error for a simple "hello world" style REST API in Scala/Play 2.6.x and I have tried everything that I can think of at this point. As far as I can tell there is not a good solution or example to be found on the internet, so even if this should be an easy fix then anyone that has a good solution would really help me out by posting it in full. I am simply trying to send a post request from `localhost:3000` (a react application using axios) to `localhost:9000` where my Scala/Play framework lives.

**THE ERRORS**

The error that I am getting on the client-side is the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/saveTest.
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

The error that I am getting on the server-side is

```
success] Compiled in 1s

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters
(see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
    play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
[warn] p.f.c.CORSFilter - Invalid CORS
request;Origin=Some(http://localhost:3000);
Method=OPTIONS;Access-Control-Request-Headers=Some(content-type)
```

**MY CODE**

I have the following in my `application.conf` file

```
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Configuration

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000", ...]
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

I've tried changing `pathPrefixes` to `/saveTest` (my endpoint), and tried changing `allowedOrigins` to simply `'https://localhost'`. I've tried changing `allowedHttpHeaders="Allow-access-control-allow-origin"`. I've tried setting `allowedOrigins`, `allowedHttpMethods`, and `allowedHttpHeaders` all to null which, according to the documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/resources/confs/filters-helpers/reference.conf) should allow everything (as should `pathPrefixes=["/"]`

My build.sbt is the following, so it should be adding the filter to the libraryDependencies:

```
name := """scalaREST"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += filters
```

According to documentation available here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#default-filters you can set the default filters like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter
import play.api.http.{ DefaultHttpFilters, EnabledFilters }

class Filters @Inject()(enabledFilters: EnabledFilters, corsFilter: CORSFilter)
  extends DefaultHttpFilters(enabledFilters.filters :+ corsFilter: _*)
```

I'm not sure exactly where that should go in my project - it doesn't say, but from other stackoverflow answers I kind of assume it should go in the root of my directory (that is `/app`). So that's where I put it.

Finally, there was one exotic stackoverflow response that said to put this class in my controllers and add it as a function to my OK responses

```
  implicit class RichResult (result: Result) {
    def enableCors =  result.withHeaders(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*"
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> 
        "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD"
        // OPTIONS for pre-flight
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> 
        "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, X-Json, 
        X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With"
        //, "X-My-NonStd-Option"
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true"
    )
  }
```

Needless to say, this did not work.

**WRAP UP**

Here is the backend for my current scala project.

https://github.com/patientplatypus/scalaproject1/tree/master/scalarest

Please, if you can, show a full working example of a CORS implementation - I cannot get anything I can find online to work. I will probably be submitting this as a documentation request to the Play Framework organization - this should not be nearly this difficult. Thank you.

Comment: OK....I know it needs to be a 200, but it's not. That's just a barebones restatement of the problem. Considering that I'm getting the error message stating on the front end that it's a CORS issue, I'm pretty sure it's a CORS issue. In no way do I mean to be dismissive, but I'm not sure how this gets me closer to a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975439/trouble-shooting-cors-in-play-framework-2-4-x/37290580#37290580 may be relevant

Comment: I've tried that solution and it did not work.

Comment: Have you debugged CORSFilter and figured out based on what it says "invalid origin"?

Comment: No I'm sorry, but to the best of my knowledge corsfilter is a plugin written by the play framework. As neither I not a third party wrote it I assume that it should,in theory work with the standard toolset. Therefore something is broken elsewhere- at least that's my reasoning. I also don't want to mess with it because I'll probably introduce more errors.

Comment: Sure, what I can tell you though is that I got the whole thing to work with play 2.6 and I did so by debugging the filters, which helped me understand what happens and which settings I needed to tweak. I'm not saying you'll find a bug there, but you'll probably see where something goes south.

Answer (score 3):

Your preflight request fails because you have a Content-Type header set

Add `content-type` to `allowedHttpHeaders` in your `application.conf` like so

```
#application.conf

play.filters.cors {
  #other cors configuration
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept", "Content-Type"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and I added these code in application.conf

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
play.filters.cors {
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "HEAD", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept", "Content-Type"]"
}
```

and now everything is OK!

[for more info](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/CorsFilter)

Answer (score 0):

For playframework version 2.8.x , we can wrap the `Response` in a function as below -

```
  def addCorsHeader (response : Result) : Result = {
    response.withHeaders(
      ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"),
      ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT")
    )
  }
```

Now in the controller, wrap the `Results` using the above function.

```
  val result = myService.swipeOut(inputParsed)
  addCorsHeader(Ok(s"$result row successfully updated. Trip complete"))
}
else {
  addCorsHeader(InternalServerError("POST body is mandatory"))
}
```